# Xamarin Setup fails, "Xamarin Bonjour Service could not be installed"

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I am getting the following error message when trying to install xamarin (Xamarin.VisualStudio_4.2.0.695.msi) on Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise.

Service "Xamarin Bonjour Service" could not be installed.  Verify that you have sufficient privileges to install system services.

[image]

I am running as local admin, so I don't know why it'd be complaining about privileges.

Comment: As a workaround, and if you don't need the Bonjour service, I'd suggest deselecting the option to install.

Answer (score 1):

I always get this error when updating xamarin. 
I have the following routine that always works. (for me)

1) When Xamarin notifies you a update is available just download and try to install it. (maybe it works this time)

2) If the install fails, cancel the setup and restart your pc. (restart is important)

3) Go under %localappdata%\MonoDevelop-4.0\Cache\TempDownload.
   In this directory you have to install the newest .msi file

PS: If the directory should change in the future you have to inspect the default install program with the process explorer. Just look for any .msi handle.

Answer (score 0):

The existing bonjour service isn't correctly deinstalled. Start cmd with admin privileges. Then try
`sc delete "bonjour service"`
In my case a restart was needed.